# Does password autofill work in the iOS Simulators in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autofill

I've created a signup form for my app and I've setup the domain association and it's all working exactly as I expected when I run it on a real iOS device.  When I land on the Username field, I can choose to auto-fill it and the password or I can tap the key icon and browse the keychain.

But... it doesn't work in the simulator.  I get:

```
2020-05-25 17:27:18.699136-0400 Detail[80182:28631661] [AutoFill] Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID: ......... due to error: iCloud Keychain is disabled
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to enable the iCloud keychain within the simulator.

Am I wrong to assume that I should be able to test password autofill in the simulator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To enable Password AutoFill in the iOS 15 simulator, You need to:

1. Open the Settings app, then select Passwords.
2. The prompt "Enter iPhone passcode to view saved passwords" will appear. Enter anything then tap "done" on the keyboard.
3. There needs to be at least one password added. Tap the + button on the navigation bar and add a dummy password.
4. Switch On the "AutoFill Passwords" toggle.

After following these steps, the Password AutoFill UI should appear in the QuickType area of the keyboard when you tap a username or password textfield.

## Note

Associated Domains is a device only feature, so when it comes to testing that the correct domain appears in the Password AutoFill area of the keyboard, you need to use a real device.

Comment: "needs to be at least one password added" was the part I was missing